# How to calculate area under curves on a 3 axis graph?

Tags: r, graph, model

I'm working on metabolic rate according to the time and the mass. For now, I have refin my curve with the MTE model with this code :

```
v.treatement<- levels(as.factor(data5$tquant))
par(new=F)



par(mfrow=c(1,1))
#v.colours <- c( "aquamarine1", "aquamarine2", "aquamarine3", "aquamarine4")
v.colours <- c("darkgoldenrod1","darkgoldenrod2","darkgoldenrod3","darkgoldenrod4")
fonctMTE<-function(M,a,b){
  a*M^(b)
}

start.values <- list(a=0.3, b=0.7)

#empty vectors
v.a.0 <- NULL
v.b.0 <- NULL
sum.0<-NULL


#start loop
for (i in (1:length(v.treatement))) 
{
  
  data1 <- subset(data5, tquant == v.treatement[i])  
  
  M<-data1$weight
  regr.data1<-nls(metabolic_rate~fonctMTE(M,a,b), data = data1, start=start.values)
  data1.pars<-regr.data1$m$getPars()
  foMTE.data1<-function(M)
  {
    data1.pars[1]*M^(data1.pars[2]) 
  }
  #tab de valeurs recup par fonction va/vb, v.a.0 recup et v.a donne
  v.a <- data1.pars[1]
  v.a.0 <- c(v.a.0, v.a )
  v.b <- data1.pars[2]
  v.b.0 <- c(v.b.0, v.b)
  
  text=c("20°C - 0.3mgC/L", "20°C - 1.5mgC/L", "28°C - 0.3mgC/L", "28°C - 1.5mgC/L")
  par(mar=c(5,6,4,1)+.1)
  
  plot(x=data1$weight, y=data1$metabolic_rate, xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,7),cex.axis=2.5, lwd=2, col=v.colours [i],
       xlab="Masse (µg)",ylab="Taux metabolique (µW)", main ="Taux metabolique de Daphnia magna en fonction de la masse", 
       cex.main=3, cex.lab=2.5)
  legend(x="bottomright",
         title="Traitement", legend = text,cex=2,text.width = strwidth(text)[1]/2,
         lty=c(1,1,1,1), col=c("darkgoldenrod1","darkgoldenrod2","darkgoldenrod3","darkgoldenrod4"), lwd=2)
  par(new=T)
  curve(foMTE.data1, from=0.001, to=, xlim=c(0,300), ylim=c(0,7), 
        col=v.colours [i],xlab="",ylab="",lwd=2, cex.axis=2)
  par(new=T)
  
  sum<-((integrate(foMTE.data1,lower =0, upper = 300)$value))
  sum.0<- c(sum.0,sum)
  
}

tab.sum <- cbind(v.treatement, sum.0)
tab.sum
par(new=F)
#retrieve values
tab.prms <- cbind(v.colours,v.treatement, v.a.0, v.b.0)
tab.prms
```

But now, the idea is to calculate the cost of biomass production, and for that, I need to calculate the area under my different treatments curves, but I have no idea how to do that... I have tried with scatterplot3D and rgl libraries to have my third awis (time) but I can't refine my curves anymore. I'm a little bit lost on how to calculate theses areas and how to make a graph of that

Here is my data :

```
structure(list(name = c("J2_S15AM", "J4_S15AM", "J4_S15BM", "J4_S15CM", 
"J5_S15AM", "J5_S15BM", "J5_S15CM", "J8_S15AM", "J8_S15BM", "J8_S15CM", 
"J2_S03A1M", "J2_S03A2M", "J2_S03A3M", "J2_S03A4M", "J2_S3A1M", 
"J2_S3A2M", "J2_S3A3M", "J2_S3A4M", "J4_S03A1M", "J4_S03A2M", 
"J4_S03A3M", "J4_S03A4M", "J4_S3A1M", "J4_S3A2M", "J4_S3A3M", 
"J4_S3A4M", "J5_S03A1M", "J5_S03A2M", "J5_S03A3M", "J5_S03A4M", 
"J5_S3A1M", "J5_S3A2M", "J5_S3A3M", "J5_S3A4M", "J7_S31M", "J7_S32M", 
"J7_S33M", "J7_S34M", "J8_S031M", "J8_S032M", "J8_S033M", "J8_S034M", 
"J8_S31M", "J8_S32M", "J8_S33M", "J8_S34M", "J2_S03AM", "J2_S03BM", 
"J2_S03CM", "J2_S03DM", "J2_S15AM", "J2_S15BM", "J2_S15CM", "J2_S15DM", 
"J4_S03AM", "J4_S03BM", "J4_S03CM", "J4_S15AM", "J4_S15BM", "J4_S15CM", 
"J4_S15DM", "J5_S03AM", "J5_S03BM", "J5_S15AM", "J5_S15BM", "J5_S15CM", 
"J5_S15DM", "J6_S03AM", "J6_S03BM", "J6_S03CM", "J6_S15AM", "J6_S15BM", 
"J6_S15CM", "J6_S15DM", "J7_S15AM", "J7_S15BM", "J7_S15CM", "J7_S15DM"
), day = c("J2", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J5", "J5", "J5", "J8", "J8", 
"J8", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J4", "J4", 
"J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J5", "J5", "J5", "J5", "J5", 
"J5", "J5", "J5", "J7", "J7", "J7", "J7", "J8", "J8", "J8", "J8", 
"J8", "J8", "J8", "J8", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", 
"J2", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J5", "J5", "J5", 
"J5", "J5", "J5", "J6", "J6", "J6", "J6", "J6", "J6", "J6", "J7", 
"J7", "J7", "J7"), quality = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), quantity = c(1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5), qual_quant = c("S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", 
"S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S03", "S03", "S03", 
"S03", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S3", 
"S3", "S3", "S3", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S3", "S3", "S3", 
"S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S3", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S3", 
"S3", "S3", "S3", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S15", "S15", "S15", 
"S15", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S03", 
"S03", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S03", "S03", "S03", "S15", 
"S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15", "S15"), temperature = c(20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), 
    time = c(63, 112, 112, 112, 135, 135, 135, 207.5, 207.5, 
    207.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 109, 
    109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 132.5, 132.5, 132.5, 132.5, 
    132.5, 132.5, 132.5, 132.5, 180.5, 180.5, 180.5, 180.5, 204, 
    204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 204, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 
    60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 60.5, 107.5, 107.5, 107.5, 107.5, 107.5, 
    107.5, 107.5, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 132, 155.5, 155.5, 
    155.5, 155.5, 155.5, 155.5, 155.5, 179.5, 179.5, 179.5, 179.5
    ), size = c(1427.39, 1625.708, 1826.186, 1675.434, 2102.514, 
    2287.498, 2465.37, 2722.146, 2754.172, 2871.61, 1456.557, 
    1454.677, 1269.442, 1280.539, 1327.833, 1546.127, 1555.498, 
    1349.435, 1424.975, 1513.477, 1639.62, 1576.638, 1853.577, 
    1656.053, 1602.587, 1692.435, 1530.399, 1674.547, 1599.997, 
    1531.013, 2303.775, 2243.73, 1917.138, 2101.636, 2996.756, 
    2760.25, 2595.753, 2369.882, 2316.411, 2356.516, 2266.426, 
    2070.88, 3167.255, 3262.57, 3231.292, 3257.285, 1451.236, 
    1508.54, 1327.43, 1536.188, 1429.08, 1319.234, 1526.69, 1517.408, 
    1506.581, 1501.196, 1370.99, 1870.489, 1941.425, 1942.186, 
    1827.395, 1337.796, 1981.024, 2179.47, 2313.671, 2220.796, 
    2385.409, 1509.715, 1642.109, 1987.531, 2114.958, 1942.499, 
    2138.743, 2565.321, 2377.469, 2381.063, 2146.886, 2427.488
    ), weight = c(2L, 47L, 52L, 44L, 71L, 69L, 79L, 167L, 193L, 
    165L, 12L, 17L, 9L, 12L, 19L, 24L, 26L, 12L, 14L, 19L, 15L, 
    18L, 39L, 33L, 27L, 32L, 23L, 27L, 18L, 30L, 66L, 68L, 45L, 
    62L, 201L, 156L, 102L, 141L, 40L, 65L, 56L, 59L, 219L, 219L, 
    192L, 224L, 20L, 22L, 14L, 17L, 21L, 19L, 26L, 29L, 20L, 
    16L, 15L, 49L, 73L, 63L, 60L, 11L, 32L, 58L, 77L, 62L, 71L, 
    20L, 23L, 29L, 34L, 46L, 71L, 94L, 70L, 71L, 52L, 72L), fecundity = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6L, 10L, 6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 11L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19L, 24L, 
    20L, 22L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L), metabolic_rate = c(0.766, 1.528, 1.927, 
    1.431, 2.807, 2.684, 3.417, 4.264, 4.389, 3.844, 0.31, 0.27, 
    0.35, 0.26, 0.67, 0.7, 0.74, 0.45, 0.45, 0.76, 0.96, 0.34, 
    1.79, 1.16, 1.31, 1.37, 0.81, 1.1, 0.54, 1.24, 2.95, 2.65, 
    2.05, 2.35, 5.06, 4.01, 3, 3.36, 2.31, 2.02, 1.59, 1.76, 
    5.44, 7.04, 4.99, 5.42, 0.413, 0.616, 0.7216, 0.5394, 0.674, 
    0.542, 1.4667, 1.449, 0.382, 0.1435, 0.2405, 2.436, 2.014, 
    3.464, 2.742, 0.172, 1.156, 2.807, 2.9, 2.213, 2.85, 0.5858, 
    1.188, 0.8748, 3.201, 2.369, 3.247, 1.1954, 3.526, 3.088, 
    2.962, 2.374), SD = c(0.048, 0.077, 0.07, 0.065, 0.065, 0.096, 
    0.078, 0.116, 0.133, 0.099, 0.034, 0.046, 0.039, 0.066, 0.034, 
    0.034, 0.046, 0.039, 0.037, 0.038, 0.08, 0.051, 0.044, 0.056, 
    0.088, 0.049, 0.048, 0.054, 0.038, 0.08, 0.085, 0.06, 0.084, 
    0.057, 0.09, 0.112, 0.075, 0.083, 0.119, 0.102, 0.083, 0.06, 
    0.141, 0.448, 0.132, 0.157, 0.036, 0.055, 0.04, 0.034, 0.055, 
    0.057, 0.037, 0.045, 0.051, 0.043, 0.039, 0.08, 0.073, 0.08, 
    0.113, 0.057, 0.081, 0.118, 0.087, 0.088, 0.098, 0.035, 0.058, 
    0.046, 0.086, 0.062, 0.173, 0.094, 0.084, 0.103, 0.056, 0.088
    ), time_maturity = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 203.583333333333, 
    203.583333333333, 203.583333333333, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 182.142857142857, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    182.142857142857, 182.142857142857, 182.142857142857, 182.142857142857, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 178.315789473684, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 178.315789473684), weight_maturity = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 186.8333, 186.8333, 186.8333, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 184.619047619048, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 184.619047619048, 184.619047619048, 184.619047619048, 
    184.619047619048, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 91.2105263157895, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 91.2105263157895), 
    tqual = c("20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S"), 
    jour = c(2.625021, 4.666704, 4.666704, 4.666704, 5.625045, 
    5.625045, 5.625045, 8.6459025, 8.6459025, 8.6459025, 2.5208535, 
    2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 
    2.5208535, 4.541703, 4.541703, 4.541703, 4.541703, 4.541703, 
    4.541703, 4.541703, 4.541703, 5.5208775, 5.5208775, 5.5208775, 
    5.5208775, 5.5208775, 5.5208775, 5.5208775, 5.5208775, 7.5208935, 
    7.5208935, 7.5208935, 7.5208935, 8.500068, 8.500068, 8.500068, 
    8.500068, 8.500068, 8.500068, 8.500068, 8.500068, 2.5208535, 
    2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 2.5208535, 
    2.5208535, 4.4792025, 4.4792025, 4.4792025, 4.4792025, 4.4792025, 
    4.4792025, 4.4792025, 5.500044, 5.500044, 5.500044, 5.500044, 
    5.500044, 5.500044, 6.4792185, 6.4792185, 6.4792185, 6.4792185, 
    6.4792185, 6.4792185, 6.4792185, 7.4792265, 7.4792265, 7.4792265, 
    7.4792265), croissance = c(-7, 38, 43, 35, 62, 60, 70, 158, 
    184, 156, 3, 8, NA, 3, 10, 15, 17, 3, 5, 10, 6, 9, 30, 24, 
    18, 23, 14, 18, 9, 21, 57, 59, 36, 53, 192, 147, 93, 132, 
    31, 56, 47, 50, 210, 210, 183, 215, 10.62, 12.62, 4.62, 7.62, 
    11.62, 9.62, 16.62, 19.62, 10.62, 6.62, 5.62, 39.62, 63.62, 
    53.62, 50.62, 1.62, 22.62, 48.62, 67.62, 52.62, 61.62, 10.62, 
    13.62, 19.62, 24.62, 36.62, 61.62, 84.62, 60.62, 61.62, 42.62, 
    62.62), color = c("20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", 
    "20S", "20S", "20S", "20S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", 
    "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S", "28S"
    ), tquant = c("201.5", "201.5", "201.5", "201.5", "201.5", 
    "201.5", "201.5", "201.5", "201.5", "201.5", "200.3", "200.3", 
    "200.3", "200.3", "203", "203", "203", "203", "200.3", "200.3", 
    "200.3", "200.3", "203", "203", "203", "203", "200.3", "200.3", 
    "200.3", "200.3", "203", "203", "203", "203", "203", "203", 
    "203", "203", "200.3", "200.3", "200.3", "200.3", "203", 
    "203", "203", "203", "280.3", "280.3", "280.3", "280.3", 
    "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "280.3", "280.3", "280.3", 
    "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "280.3", "280.3", "281.5", 
    "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "280.3", "280.3", "280.3", "281.5", 
    "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5", "281.5"
    ), treatment = c("S1520", "S1520", "S1520", "S1520", "S1520", 
    "S1520", "S1520", "S1520", "S1520", "S1520", "S0320", "S0320", 
    "S0320", "S0320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S0320", 
    "S0320", "S0320", "S0320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S320", 
    "S0320", "S0320", "S0320", "S0320", "S320", "S320", "S320", 
    "S320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S0320", "S0320", 
    "S0320", "S0320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S320", "S0328", 
    "S0328", "S0328", "S0328", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", 
    "S0328", "S0328", "S0328", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", 
    "S0328", "S0328", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S0328", 
    "S0328", "S0328", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", "S1528", 
    "S1528", "S1528", "S1528")), row.names = c("28", "78", "79", 
"80", "112", "113", "114", "218", "219", "220", "912", "1012", 
"1112", "1212", "1712", "1810", "1912", "2012", "372", "382", 
"392", "402", "452", "462", "472", "482", "952", "962", "972", 
"98", "1032", "1042", "1052", "1062", "1432", "1442", "1452", 
"1462", "165", "166", "167", "168", "173", "174", "175", "176", 
"2310", "2410", "2510", "2610", "2710", "2810", "29", "307", 
"1081", "1091", "1101", "1111", "1121", "1131", "1141", "1851", 
"1861", "1881", "1891", "1901", "1911", "2101", "2111", "2121", 
"2131", "2141", "2151", "2161", "2441", "2451", "2461", "2471"
), class = "data.frame")
```